# Do I have to publish my app under the same Google account that I configured Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, developer-console

Under Google account #1, I have Google+ and Google maps enabled/configured for my Android app. In the app, I am using the App Id that I configured under this account which allows me to use G+ sign in and Google Maps.

Will I be able to publish this app under a completely separate Google account and have the Google Services still work?

I've looked around but couldn't find any information stating whether or not I can (or should) use the same account to configure Google Play Services and publish the app.

Comment: go for it. dont require same account.

Comment: You can publish your app under any google account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that is mandatory, and in the past I have done these things with separate Google accounts

Answer (score 2):

You are free to use a different google account for publishing your app in the store [[Play developer account]](https://play.google.com/publish/apps-games/index.html), other than the one you used for configuring google services viz Maps, Admob, G+ [[Google developer console]](https://console.developers.google.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Google Account. There is not compulsory that you have to publish your app under the same Google account that you configured Google Play Services.

Its not compulsory thatPlay services and Publish account be same.

All you need to do is to keep KeyStore file safe as once you lose your Keystore file its too hard to Upload new Version for that Application.